# Fréchet derivative of a function of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $$P:C[0,1]\to C[0,1],P(f)(x)=1+kxf(x)\int_0^1 \frac{f(s)}{x+s}ds$$

I want to find $P'(f)$. Now, I'm somewhat confused about how one uses the definition of the Fréchet derivative in this case to differentiate with respect to $f$. Clearly, we need $$P(f+h)-P(f)-o(h)=Ah,$$

where $h$ is a function. But if this is the case, then the $P(f)$ is Fréchet differentiable means it satisfies

$$\lim\limits_{h(x)\to 0} \frac{\|P(f(x)+h(x))-DP(f(x))h(x)\|}{\|h(x)\|}=0.\mbox{  $\textbf(*)$ }$$

Then this would mean that $h(x)$ is approaching the constant function $h(x)\equiv 0$. Is this correct?

Also, is my understanding correct that $o(h)$ means the error term for the expression in **$\mbox{$\textbf{(*)}$}$**?

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Comment: Yes, $o(h)$ is an error term. Search for "Landau symbols" if its meaning is unclear. If $P$ is Fréchet differentiable, then its Fréchet derivative is the same is its Gâteaux derivative, which is calculated more easily.

Comment: You need to specify what the domain and target space of $P$ are, though. Otherwise, those norms don't make sense.

Comment: @MichaelLee Edited. Can you please clarify if my understanding of the application of the definition of the Fréchet derivative is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(f)(x) = 1 + kxf(x)\int_0^1 \frac{f(s)}{x+s}ds$$

Plugging in $f+h$, we have:

$$P(f+h)(x) = 1 + kx(f(x)+h(x)) \int_0^1 \frac{f(s)+h(s)}{x+s}ds$$
$$ = 1 + kxf(x)\int_0^1 \frac{f(s)}{x+s}ds + xh(x) \int_0^1 \frac{f(s)}{x+s} ds + xf(x) \int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s} ds +  xh(x) \int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s}ds$$

Now subtract $P(f)(x)$:

$$P(f+h)(x) - P(f)(s) = xh(x) \int_0^1 \frac{f(s)}{x+s} ds + xf(x) \int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s} ds  + xh(x) \int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s} ds$$

We are looking for something that is linear in $h(x)$. The last term seems to depend on $h$ quadratically, indeed by the mean value theorem for integrals we have that there is an $\eta \in [0,1]$ such that $$xh(x) \int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s} ds = x\frac{h(x)h(\eta)}{x+\eta},$$ this is assuming $x > 0$.

With that in mind, let's guess that the linear operator in $h$ is $$Ah(x) = xh(x) \int_0^1 \frac{f(s)}{x+s} ds + xf(x) \int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s} ds.$$

Indeed, $Ah(x)$ is linear in $h$, so it is a viable candidate. Moreover,

$$P(f+h)(x) - Pf(x) - Ah(x) = xh(x)\int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s} ds.$$

Hence you are left with demonstrating $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{xh(x) \int_0^1 \frac{h(s)}{x+s} ds}{h(x)} = 0.$$

Comment: The mean value theorem will work for you as long as $x > 0$. For $x = 0$, you will have to use some limiting argument together with the fact that the integral is multiplied by $x$ to keep it small.

Comment: Since you have added that $P$ is a mapping from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$ this limit must be demonstrated with the norm of that space. I am assuming that this is the usual supremum norm.

Comment: Edit: Corrected a multiplication error in the beginning. Don't forget F.O.I.L. kids...